# Loading large data from Postgres table to S3 using Airflow's PostgresHook

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to load data from a Postgres table to S3 using Airflow, the PostgresToS3 operator works for all tables except one which is a very large table. The task runs for some time ~800s and then stops without any logs. This seems to because the connection is getting closed after some timeout period. I tried to do a `cursor.execute("SET statement_timeout = 0")` before `cursor.execute(self.sql)` Is there any way I can fix this?

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.html

Comment: Please, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980922/how-to-export-large-data-from-postgres-to-s3-using-cloud-composer). Have you looked for logs?

Comment: No use, I tried checking the StackDriver logs as well, nothing useful there as well.

Comment: Have you installed all libraries needed to run postgres_hook?

Comment: @muscat Yes, I have several other pipelines using postgres_hook.

Comment: Probably there are some limitations. How large is your dataset? Have you checked your kubernetes workers, how environment behaves while transporting data?